# How to iterate random_path in the below code?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to print random_path in the below code. Can I show all random paths using list

```
random_path = nx.generate_random_paths(twitch_G,100, path_length = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you just need to put `random_path` inside list `list( random_path )`

```
gr = nx.gnp_random_graph(10, 0.6)
list( nx.generate_random_paths(gr, sample_size=2, path_length=4) )
```

result:

```
[[1, 9, 0, 4, 7], [6, 7, 3, 0, 5]]
```